# How to get rid of these strange characters in PHP?

Tags: php

I have some variables that out outputting text with strange characters like:

```
It's the Pughes Submitted by â€¨Mukpuddy Animationâ€¨ History of Sicily in One Hundred Seconds Submitted by â€¨Turi Scandurraâ€¨: â€¨â€¨Cat Me! if You Can Submitted by â€¨Nik Ritzmann Mukpuddy shows us that poo can be cute in the hilarious "It's
```

and:

```
more funny videos *** ÐšÐ°Ðº-Ñ‚Ð¾ ÑÐ¸Ð´ÐµÐ» Ð¸ Ð¾Ñ‚ Ð½ÐµÑ‡Ð° Ð´ÐµÐ»Ð°Ñ‚ÑŒ ÑÐ¼Ð¾Ñ‚Ñ€ÐµÐ» ÐºÐ¾Ñ€Ð¾Ñ‚ÐµÐ½ÑŒÐºÐ¸Ðµ Ð²Ð¸Ð´ÐµÐ¾Ñ€Ð¾Ð»Ð¸ÐºÐ¸, ÐºÐ¾Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ€Ñ‹Ðµ Ñ…Ð¾Ð·ÑÐµÐ²Ð° ÑÐ½ÑÐ»Ð¸ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾ ÑÐ²Ð¾Ð¸Ñ… ÐºÐ¾Ñ‚Ð¾Ð². ÐÐ°ÐºÐ¾Ð¿Ð¸Ð»Ð¾ÑÑŒ
```

What function do I have to wrap the variables in, in order to make these texts display properly?

I tried:

```
utf8_decode($variable_name);
```

but that outputted:

```
more funny videos *** �?ак-�?о сидел и о�? не�?а дела�?�? смо�?�?ел ко�?о�?ен�?кие видео�?олики, ко�?о�?�?е �?озяева сняли п�?о свои�? ко�?ов. Накопилос�?
```

Comment: Needs more information on where the data comes from and what character set you are using on your page

Comment: Did you changed the encoding of the .php file to UTF-8?

Comment: I'm using charset=utf-8" in the meta tag of the page. The data comes from a mysql database. The description in the database is exactly the same as the one being outputted.

Comment: You mean the data is broken in the database already? Which database library are you using?

Comment: Have you checked the Collation type for that field in the Database? if you are after UTF8 then it should be 'utf8_unicode_ci' ...